# List item component is not updating on state change in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know it is a common issue, I saw many resources but I am unable to solve my case.

My code is:

```js
const { Component } = React

const Row = ({children}) => <tr>{children}</tr>;
const Col = ({children}) => <td>{children}</td>;
const DashboardTemplate = ({children}) => <table>{children}</table>;

class AddData extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [1, 2],
  }

  handleAdd = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = this.state.items.length
    let newItems = data + 1
    this.setState({
      items: [...this.state.items, newItems],
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DashboardTemplate>

          <Row gutter={(16, 16)}>
            <Col className="gutter-row" span={18}>
              <div className="gutter-box">
                <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
                {this.state.items.map(item => (
                  <p>{item}</p>
                ))}
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </DashboardTemplate>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddData />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

My state is updating on button press, but component is not updating. Where is my mistake?

Comment: can you post the working example  https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-snyder-cz5hp

Comment: Since you'd provided nearly everything needed for it, I converted your code block into a Stack Snippet so that it was runnable, making a couple of reasonable assumptions / substitutions. For next time, [here's how to do that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: As you can see, the component in the snippet updates when the state changes. I can't immediately see a problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: Likewise a React-only version (w/o ant) seems to work fine on codesandbox. Check your console for errors etc.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-3102020-1-n2h62 - Component does get updated - can you please explain what actually needs to happen here?

Comment: I want the exact result you gave. But, it is not happening in my project @muddassir

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: no, even my state items are changing properly.. is this might occur for ant design v4?